# AWS proxy without SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, proxy, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel

I'm using an EC2 instance as a proxy for my browser. The problem is that I have to have a constantly running SSH tunnel to be able to use it and for some reason it sometimes fails. I tried using the SSH options `-oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=4` and that helped a bit but the tunnel still drops sometimes. Is it possible to somehow use the proxy without a tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to keep connection from you server to the EC2 instance, if you wish to use proxy. How else this could work?

But you can use `autossh` to automatically restore your tunnel, when it fails.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/606077)

Comment: @Ramhound why do you think?

Comment: I don't explain comments generated by the review system anymore.  I have more user argue with me when I do.  I am under no obligation to do so, the comment itself, explains my decision.

Comment: @Ramhound I know how these generated comments work and what do they mean. I was asking what is leading you to think this does not answer the question. Yes, there is voting system so we will see if the other users will think the same.

Comment: "But you can use autossh to automatically restore your tunnel, when it fails." **How** provide specifics.  I won't be back.